# Why does hibernate give me this error when I put the transient tag?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am trying to fix the vulnerabilities that Kiuwan is indicating to me.

The problem is that one of them is adding the Transient type to a Date type variable, when I do it it gives me the following error.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: com.pack.keys.MyClassKey has no persistent id property: com.pack.logic.MyClass.id
```

If i dont put transient in Date dont show the error and my project compile.

### MyClass

```
@Table(name = "tablename")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class MyClass{

    @EmbeddedId
    private MyClassKey id;

    private String string1;

    //Many String more...
```

### MyClassKey

```
@Embeddable
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class MyClassKey implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private transient String string1;

    private transient String string2;

    private transient String string3;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private transient Date myDate;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because transient is excluding attributes from Hibernate. It has the same effect as adding `@Transient` annotation:

https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/persistence/Transient.html

Comment: I have other class with BigDecimal, Strings and Integers, with same structure and compile, why only not compile when put transient in a Date type. And the problem is a need put transient because Kiuwan think dont put transient is a vulnerability.

Comment: As I wrote transient excludes attributes from persistence. You CANNOT use transient if you want to persist the attributes!